# Django user online status and last activity time

Tags: django, django-models

Do you have any idea how can i find online status of a user? It also would be nice if i could get last time the user was active. I'm using django's User model:

```
manager = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/zalew/django-online-status/wiki/Home

Comment: @madzohan I'm using django 1.8 and django-online-status 0.1.0 in not compatible with it

Comment: I've just googled for you :D you can always make it compatible for django 1.8 since it is open source ;)

Answer (score 0):

Django provides an `is_authenticated()` method for this:

```
def check_user_is_logged_in(user):
    if user.is_authenticated():
        # Do something
    return None
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking for last activity time of a user, potentially a third party.

Comment: Yeah you are right but i don't know why when i log out with one user and log in with another `user.is_authenticated` returns true for the first one!!!

Answer (score 0):

Last login is already stored on the default [user object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) which would give you last login time.

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for for example a user logs in at 4 PM and reloads a page for example at 4:10 and the logs out. i want to get 4:10 not 4

Comment: In that case you'd need to have a custom user model with a last_seen attribute which is set on user logout

Answer (score 0):

This Blog should do justice to your Problem http://www.djangocurrent.com/2011/07/django-using-cashing-to-track-online.html